# Loading optimal texture size

Tags: android, libgdx

I was thinking of using a 1920 x 1080 resolution as a template, as it is currently almost the highest resolution. I would build all textures according to full HD. But then the RAM would take a big load. Could I go for something like 1366x768 (which uses 2x less pixels than full HD), and then scale it to full HD or would the loss in quality be huge?

Comment: The GLES hardware on many devices requires power-of-2 texture sizes, so 1366x768 would actually be 2048x1024. To get a sense for quality loss, take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc , which adjusts the Surface size for some simple textures... it looks pretty reasonable until you get to the extreme. Perceived quality will depend upon the nature of the textures (e.g. are there lots of very fine details), the amount of motion, and the characteristics of the display device.

Comment: I see that the medium and hd are not so much different. If you mean that 1366x768 takes up the same amount of ram as 2048x1024, well I tried it and it's not true, well I tested it for a few different sizes, and it does not seem to apply. Or maybe you mean something else?

Comment: I'm referring to the size of the texture image after it's been uploaded to the GPU. Presumably libgdx takes care of that stuff behind the scenes. Some devices can handle NPOT textures, some can't.

Comment: Just a note - Google play store allows max 100MB for apk file size. Some "special"  techniques are neede for larger apps/games.